# Can I backup Serverless SQL pool Database?

Tags: serverless, azure-synapse

Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pool endpoint can have multiple databases. Serverless SQL pool has no local storage; only metadata objects are stored in databases.
Question:

1. Can I backup these databases manually? I don't see anything in the portal, maybe through Powershell or Azure-CLI?
2. Is there any automated backup or restore point taken?
3. Is my only option to keep all the metadata in source control (which I should keep anyway) and deploy from there in case of a disaster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to backup Serverless SQL Pool databases. Please, file feature proposal on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics). 
Also, check [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/generate-create-drop-external-table-scripts-on-synapse-sql-using/ba-p/1365020), where you can see how you can use PowerShell DbaTools to script Synapse SQL objects which may help you.